# Async request in useEffect doesn't work like async

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to take data from a backend,it takes data , but it doesn't display data on the page until the component calls componentDidUpdate() , but with the second function it works. I think that the it mounting component before the taking data , i tried to use 'uselayouteffect' but it didn't solve the problem , by using console.log , i understood that the problem in the my async functions , but the functions are the same (i mean structure) .

useEffect:

```
useEffect( () => {

    console.log('ProfileUseEffect')

    getUserInfo().then( (response) => {
        console.log(response)
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })


    loadAllSessions().then( (response) => {
        console.log(response)
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })

}, [])
```

function that doesn't work correctly :

```
    const getUserInfo = async () => {

    console.log('ThisShitGonnaWork')

    const requestData = {
        "client": requestClient,
        "key": requestKey,
        "data":{
            "action":"getInfo",
            "token": accessTokenCookie['access_token'],
        }
    }

    try{
        const response = await axios.post(
            backendUrl + 'user' , requestData
        )

        setUserAccountInfo(response?.data?.message)

        typeof  userAccountInfo.userlogin !== 'undefined' &&  setUserLogin(userAccountInfo.userlogin)
        typeof  userAccountInfo.username !== 'undefined' &&  setUserName(userAccountInfo.username)
        typeof  userAccountInfo.userrole !== 'undefined' &&  setUserRole(userAccountInfo.userrole)

    }catch (err){
        console.log(err)
    }
    
}
```

function that works correctly:

```
    const loadAllSessions = async () => {
    
    const requestData = {
        "client": requestClient,
        "key": requestKey,
        "data":{
            "action":"getActiveSessions",
            "token": accessTokenCookie['access_token'],
        }
    }

    try{
        const response = await axios.post(
            backendUrl + 'user', requestData
        )
        response?.data?.message?.activeSessions.forEach( (elem , idx ) => {
            updateUserSessionsMap(idx , elem)
        })

    }catch (err){
        console.log(err)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because of this part:

```
 try{
        const response = await axios.post(
            backendUrl + 'user' , requestData
        )

        setUserAccountInfo(response?.data?.message)

        typeof  userAccountInfo.userlogin !== 'undefined' &&  setUserLogin(userAccountInfo.userlogin)
        typeof  userAccountInfo.username !== 'undefined' &&  setUserName(userAccountInfo.username)
        typeof  userAccountInfo.userrole !== 'undefined' &&  setUserRole(userAccountInfo.userrole)

    }catch (err){
        console.log(err)
    }
```

You are doing `setUserAccountInfo` and then you are expecting in next line that you will access that new state by inspecting `typeof  userAccountInfo...`, and you will not, because state update is async and you will access new state only after rerender(in next function call) - state is being accessed from closure which recreates on each rerender.

Rewrite to this:

```
try{
        const response = await axios.post(
            backendUrl + 'user' , requestData
        )
        
        const accountInfo = response?.data?.message;
        setUserAccountInfo(accountInfo)
        

        typeof  accountInfo.userlogin !== 'undefined' && setUserLogin(accountInfo.userlogin)
        typeof  accountInfo.username !== 'undefined' &&  setUserName(accountInfo.username)
        typeof  accountInfo.userrole !== 'undefined' &&  setUserRole(accountInfo.userrole)

    }catch (err){
        console.log(err)
    }
```

You need to preserve value you are passing into `setUserAccountInfo` and then use that value(and not the current state) to do some additional checks and state updates.